# Is there any way to make camel-jetty dynamically reload the key store once the key store is changed?

Tags: java, https, apache-camel

We meet a problem when we use https in camel-jetty. Once the key store file is changed(like delete or add a certification), how can we make the change take effect? Seems like by default,  camel-jetty won't reload the change dynamically.

The sample code:

```
JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = getContext().getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);
SslSelectChannelConnector sslConnector = new SslSelectChannelConnector();
SslContextFactory sslFactory = sslConnector.getSslContextFactory();
sslFactory.setNeedClientAuth(true);
sslFactory.setKeyStore("d:" + File.separator +"serverkeystore");
sslFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("serverkey");
sslFactory.setKeyStorePassword("serverkeystore");
sslFactory.setTrustStore("d:" + File.separator +"servertruststore");
sslFactory.setTrustStorePassword("servertruststore");
Map<Integer, SslSelectChannelConnector> connectors = new HashMap<Integer, SslSelectChannelConnector>();
connectors.put(443, sslConnector);
jettyComponent.setSslSocketConnectors(connectors);   
from("jetty:https://0.0.0.0/httpsservice")
    .id("httpsserver")
    .process(new Processor(){
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            exchange.getOut().setBody("OK");
            exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 200);
        }
    });
```

But when we change the key store file dynamically, unless restart the application, the change won't take effect. Is there any way to make the change take effect?

Thanks

Comment: This is being discussed outside stackoverflow. Please add comment when you post your questions in multiple places. http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/If-camel-jetty-camel-http-can-dynamically-load-keystore-trustsore-changes-tp5684697.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an `SSLContext` (and pass it via an `SslContextFactory`) using a custom `X509KeyManager` and a custom `X509TrustManager` that will change its return values dynamically, instead of being loaded once and for all.

For performance reasons, instead of  reloading the keystores every time one of their methods are called, I would cache the result and reload it once in a while only (perhaps every 5 minutes, this really depends on the usage you expect).

Answer (score 0):

Keep two camel contexts alive with the same config. Apply the load balancer pattern http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html. Then periodically, check the keystore file for updates, if updates, take down one at a time. Make sure the load balancer is aware wich context to fire at.

Okay, I must admit I have not really thought it all through. The SSL part might make it a bit tricky. But it should be doable.